# Heroku : App not compatible with buildpack: https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/php.tgz

Tags: php, heroku, dropbox

I have hosted a php file in dropbox and tried to build the app in heroku but i keep having this error. I have selected the php build-pack in heroku heroku/php.

Any idea folks?

Thanks